# Tableau Quick Filter- How do I make it display a description but filter on a key?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to present the user with the user-friendly description field but have that selection translate into a filter on an indexed field for performance.

For example, say I have a Widget table with two fields and 10 million rows.  The fields are WidgetKey integer, WidgetDescription string.  I need let the user pick from a list of WidgetDescription, but in the SQL it should to filter on the value WidgetKey.

Can I configure a Tableau quick filter to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This is not the answer however it is answered in the comments

> `The only alternative you have is to apply aliases to each WidgetKey
>   in Tableau.`

========================

Just make a new calculated field that provides the description and use that as the filter.

Name: WidgetDescription

```
CASE WidgetKey
    WHEN 'SomeKey' THEN 'Some Description'
    WHEN etc..
END
```

Comment: How does that differ from just adding a filter for WidgetDescription?  I want the filter to be on WidgetKey so my query plan can use the index.  I just want the label to be WidgetDescription.

Comment: But then the query plan will not be able to use my index on WidgetKey and I will be doing a table scan through 10 miillion records on WidgetDescription.  Am I missing something silly here?

Comment: The only alternative you have is to apply aliases to each WidgetKey in Tableau.

Comment: Aliases!  This was just what I needed.  Thanks.